# SQLite: How to count references to each ROWID in a table, then insert the count

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need some help writing a SQL statement. I have two tables in a SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  item_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ref_count INTEGER
);
```

I'm seeking a SQLite statement that will be like the following pseudocode:

```
for each row in items
    items[ row ].ref_count = SELECT COUNT(users.item_id) 
                               FROM users 
                              WHERE users.item_id=row;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [`REPLACE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) command as follows:

```
REPLACE INTO  items (item_id, ref_count)
SELECT        item_id, COUNT(*) AS ref_count
FROM          users
GROUP BY      item_id;
```

Test case:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (6, 3);
```

Result after running the `REPLACE` query:

```
SELECT * FROM items;

item_id       ref_co
------------  ------
1             3     
2             2     
3             1
```

Adding some further items:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (7, 1);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (8, 4);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (9, 4);
```

And after re-running the `REPLACE` query:

```
SELECT * FROM items;

item_id       ref_co
------------  ------
1             4     
2             2     
3             1     
4             2
```